# Unable to connect Metabase with Oracle Database

Tags: linux, oracle, business-intelligence, ojdbc, metabase

good afternoon! 
Sorry by my english, im learning to write without using Google Translate, so, Let's go! 
I tried to run Metabase in my local lab and, i read the poor many documentation who exist in internet to help in this issue...
My lab:

```
VM Ubuntu 22.04
Metabase 0.47.8
Plugin ojdbc11
and db Metabase in psql (not H2)
```

Starting my metabase, i run this:

```
export MB_DB_CONNECTION_URI="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/metabase?user=USER&password=PASSWORD"
```

```
java -jar /opt/metabase/metabase.jar
```

And Metabase started e running ok. But, when i try to add a db Oracle, i has this problem:
[oracle connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGCOV.png)

just showing 2 tables i dont recognize..
[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcFpK.png)

and, if i search the database and my tables using Oracle SQL Developer, i can see all:
[ORacleDB SQL Dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIrFF.png), [Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfEb1.png), [Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObJDV.png)

I need help and i'm sorry if i open this Answre incorrect, but i am new here and new with metabase and Oracle.

Im expecting some light to help me solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem just like this:

Searching in my Oracle Database all tables with more than 0 bytes of data (my database have 7936 tables) and result are 1295 tables.

I create a special user for metabase and this connection, grant select just for this 1295 tables e set up the user into metabase/oracle connection and voilá...

Metabase find al tables i want. Now, i need to wait sync and starting to use Metabase.